# Storing Data Temporarily in JTable or Temporary table in Oracle

Tags: java, swing, oracle10g

I am developing an Inventory managemant System using Java Swing and Oracle. In that I have an Internal frame called Purchase.In this, when a user press ENTER button after filling up the form, data get inserted into actual table. But I want the data to be stored in a temporary table or temporarily in JTable until user press SAVE button. After pressing the SAVE button, the data from JTable or temporary table(may contain multiple rows) should get inserted into actual table. Please share your experience or idea on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "After pressing the SAVE button, the data from JTable or temporary table(may contain multiple rows) should get inserted into actual table. **Please share your experience or idea on this."**

Use a `DefaultTableModel` for adding the information into the `JTable`

```
String[] columnNames = { "Data 1", "Data 2", "Data 3 };
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Then you can gather the info from the form and add it as a row to the model

```
String data1 = textField1.getText();
String data2 = textField2.getText();
String data3 = textField3.getText();
model.addRow( new Object[] { data1, data2, data3 } );
```

When you want to save the data, just use `DefualtTableModel`s

- `public Vector getDataVector()` - Returns the Vector of Vectors that contains the table's data values. The vectors contained in the outer vector are each a single row of values.

  ```
  Vector<Vector<String>> data = model.getDataVector();
  ```

Just iterate through the `Vector` using `PreparedStatement` and use of [transaction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html)

See [**DefaultTableModel API**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) and [**How to Use Tables**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [*Using PreparedStatement**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 0):

Store them as a List of data objects in memory.  Once the user presses save, then write out that List of objects to the database.